# SharePoint Online takes hour to install the sharepoint hosted app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, deployment, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to write SharePoint hosted app and connecting to microsoft online Sharepoint portal (dev site).

It takes more than an hour to install the app on the sharepoint after I press `F5` in Visual Dtudio. Similarly while uninstalling the app, again it is stuck and takes a long time to uninstall, and sometime it does not uninstall the app. This happens only for SharePoint hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely contact Microsoft support. This could be a bug in Microsoft's environment.  My experience with SharePoint Online has been that it is slow.  However, it shouldn't take you an hour to deploy, unless your app is huge and your internet is slow.